# Converting string to int for check answer

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, swift

For my math question app I have two random numbers generated then I have 4 buttons as answers. I want to check the answer if the user pushes the right button but it seems not to work.

**num1 and num2 are the labels** which the random numbers are generated in so technically

> num1.text = "(randomnum1)"
>
> and num2.text = "(randomnum2)" Thanks.

I have the following code under button1 IBaction

```
    var sum = (num1) + (num2)
    if btn1.titleLabel = (sum){
            check.text = "right"            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

```
if btn1.titleLabel.toInt()! == sum
```

or

```
if btn1.titleLabel == String(sum)
```

consider the difference between `=` (assign) and `==` (is equal)

to assign a number to a label use

```
num1.text = "\(randomnum1)"
```

I recommend to use backing `Int` variables like `randomnum1` to hold the random numbers which can used for the math for example

```
var randomnum1 = 0, randomnum2 = 0 // instance variables of the class

randomnum1 = randomFuntion()
randomnum2 = randomFuntion()

num1.text = String(randomnum1)
num2.text = String(randomnum2)
```

now the labels contain the string values of the random numbers, but you can do the math with the associated variables.

```
var sum = randomnum1 + randomnum2
```

after that you can check the result as mentioned above

```
if btn1.titleLabel == String(sum) {
   check.text = "right"   
}
```

Comment: i understand that but how do I add num1 and num2 for the sum variable because num1 and num2 are labels but have random numbers generated in them?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of new to this so just wanted to know what do you mean by saying use backing int variables.

Comment: where do i view the edited post it is still the same on my webpage

Comment: Ok i saw the edited post but do i just write String?

Comment: Also i already have randomnum1 and randomnum2 = to arc4random. i did num1.text = string (randomnum1). But it is still not working. I wrote all this under the buttons which are the answer choices like multiple choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do some convert before you add num1 and num2. (convert strings to integers before adding them up, also, you should convert string to integer fisrt when comparing sum and btn.titleLabel)

Comment: i understand that but how do I add num1 and num2 for the sum variable because num1 and num2 are labels but have random numbers generated in them?